# SwiftUI/GeoFire - How to ensure an asynchronous Firebase function completes before updating variable in View

Tags: ios, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, geofire

I am new to SwiftUI and one thing I am struggling to understand is how do we update the view correctly given Firebase calls are asynchronous.

```
@main
struct Application: App {
    @State var showLoading = false //how to stop loading ONLY after someFunc completes?
    @State var userList: [user] = []
    var body: some Scene {
        if (showLoading)
        {
             VStack{
             //show screen loading
             }
        }else{
            VStack{
               //present actual screen content
            }.onAppear(){
                showLoading = true
                getUserList(){ completed, resultList in
                    if completed{
                        userList = resultList
                        showLoading = false
                }
            }
        }
     }
}

func getUserList(completion: @escaping (Bool,Array<user>) -> ())
{
    var arrayUsers = [user]()    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    //Firebase call below to retrieve a list of users
    db.collection("someCollection").getDocuments { (snap, err) in
          //some logic and validations and add respective users pack to the array
          arrayUsers.append(foundUser)     
    }

    //GeoFire call to see nearby user
    Fd.GEO_REF.query.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key, location) in
          //some logic and validations and add respective users pack to the array
         arrayUsers.append(foundUser)
    })
    completion(true, arrayUsers)
}
```

The problem is:

1. `completion` always returns in `getUserList` (right away) even when the function (a Firebase/GeoFire query) is still running/retrieving data from Firebase Realtime Database.
2. GeoFire query.observe keeps "observing" and unable to remove it. All I want is to load the userList once. Not forever.

Is there a way to "pause" the view and keep loading the screen until the function actually completes while removing the observer?

Not sure whether I am making sense here, if not, I am happy to clarify and learn more about it.

Many thanks in advance for help!

Comment: I also checked removeObserver:withHandle: or removeAllObservers: does not work...Source: https://github.com/imperiumlabs/GeoFirestore-iOS

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there.

As you correctly mention, `observe` is an async function which will return its result in the trailing closure. To signal completion to the code calling `getUserList`, you'll want to move the line calling *your* completion handler into the closure, like this:

```swift
func getUserList(completion: @escaping (Bool,Array<user>) -> ())
{
    var arrayUsers = [user]()    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    //Firebase call below to retrieve a list of users
    db.collection("someCollection").getDocuments { (snap, err) in
          //some logic and validations and add respective users pack to the array
          arrayUsers.append(foundUser)     
    }

    //GeoFire call to see nearby user
    Fd.GEO_REF.query.observe(.keyEntered, with: { (key, location) in
          //some logic and validations and add respective users pack to the array
         arrayUsers.append(foundUser)
         self.completion(true, arrayUsers)
    })
    
}
```

That being said, I think you should take a different approach altogether, and use a view model with a published property that holds your users.

Your view can then subscribe to the published property, thus automatically updating the UI whenever the snapshot listener receives an update.

Check out this article on our Medium channel for an example that shows how to use RTDB in a watchOS app: [Get Started with Firebase Realtime Database and watchOS | by Rohit Rajendran | Firebase Developers | Medium](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/get-started-with-firebase-realtime-db-and-watchos-84f3b70d36e). You should be able to apply the approach in the article to you app.

Comment: Hi Peter, seems like the link you have provided are only available for premium user. Meanwhile i tried putting the .completion function inside the .observe function, but it didn't work as it goes into an infinity loop. Seems like query.observe (.keyEntered) keeps calling itself. I tried using .removeObserver function from GeoFire but it didn't work. How do i "stop observing". I only want to load the list once.

Comment: Try opening the link in an anonymous tab.